# Hiding User ID from URL in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, routes

just wondering is it possible to edit URL in MVC?

For example, I login to the profile under the user id = 1, so the URL generated will be

`https://something/Home/Profile?id=1`

So when the user edit the link to

`https://something/Home/Profile?id=2`

They will be able to visit another user profile

Is it possible to make it to

`https://something/Home/Profile`

So that user will not be able to edit the link

Another case is that when the user typed in other ids to the URL, the page will still maintain on their own profile page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to hide url parameter

```
    public ActionResult RedirectToProfile(string id)
    {
        TempData["UserId"] = id;
        return RedirectToAction("Profile");
    }

    public ActionResult Profile()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["UserId"]);
        //Do some stuff
        return View();
    }
```

Another solution is You can encrypt the query string and verify at controller side.

Hope you this will helps you.

Mark it correct if this helps you.